# Насколько эффективен такой метод исключений - если ошибка, то перевыполнить код, где была ошибка

Tags: логика, исключения

ошибки ловятся методом try {} catch {}

p.s. программка простая. каждый класс выполняется не более чем 0.100 сек. так что пользователь = 1 (0.100 сек * 10 ошибок) секунду может подождать

Comment: А какого характера ошибка? И почему она должна исчезнуть при повторном исполнении кода?

Comment: @avp В том то и дело - что за ошибка, никому ни интересно. Исчезнет ли она - никто ни знает.

Comment: А как Вы вообще тогда отличаете ошибки от правильных результатов?

Comment: @avp буду писать на java и использовать try {} catch {}

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос. Смотря какая ошибка. Если ее причины имеют характер вероятностный (например, задержка доставки пакетов в сети), то можно и повторить. Но причина постоянная (например, неправильные данные), то смысл? По любому, должен быть лимит повторностей: а вдруг стохастическая ошибка приобрела постоянный характер (сломался сервер или не работает сеть, например).

Comment: @danpetruk? может, вы лучше код покажете?

Comment: @danpetruk, @mikillskegg мягко прокомментировал Вашу затею, 

я же (после упоминания try/catch) скажу, что это **бредовый** подход.

Comment: @avp первый ответ на вопрос есть )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Эффективность обратно пропорциональна повторяемости ошибки. Это при условии что код изолированный и при ошибке не ломает систему. Если даже потенциально может что то сломать, то такой подход приведёт к постепенному уничтожению :-)

В любом случае лучше осмысленно реагировать на ошибки и понимать от чего оно произошло и чем это грозит.